# How do I extract the digits from an integer and store them in different variables?

Tags: c

C Programming beginner here. I want to input an integer from the user and store each digit in a different variable.

As if the user inputs '123456', then int a=1, int b=2, int c=3 and so on. How can I do this?

I know how to calculate the number of digits in an integer and 'display' each digit one by one, but how to store them in different variables?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: except using many variables, you can use int array.

Comment: Is reading the input character by character an option?

Comment: @MANJURULHAQUE I have not yet studied arrays, so please tell me if there is any way using many variables?

Comment: Please focus on the specific programming problem by showing an [mre] of everything you have. I assume you have already managed to read the input and store it in a variable. Please show that. It makes proposing solutions much easier. It also matches [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: An array is essentially just a collection of variables, so yes

Comment: @Yunnosch I can read the input character by character but I want it to be stored in integer form

Comment: So when you printed the digits, why didn't you just try to assign them to a variable instead?

Comment: @klutt I did it in a loop, I can't assign different variables in a loop. Like I can assign a variable to '1' in '123456' ( the single quote here is only for input), but when the loop is iterated, I desire not to store '2' in the same variable

Comment: "I did it in a loop" Please show that as an MRE. [edit] your question to do that.

Comment: Then unroll the loop.

Comment: @klutt True, but maybe a little abstract a phrasing for an unexperienced programmer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yep, but it's hard to give a good answer when the questioner insist on avoiding the correct tools to use. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Useful tools:

- `/` operator : divide numbers and return the quotient
- `%` operator : divide numbers and return the remainder

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num = 123456;

    int a = (num / 100000) % 10;
    int b = (num /  10000) % 10;
    int c = (num /   1000) % 10;
    int d = (num /    100) % 10;
    int e = (num /     10) % 10;
    int f = (num /      1) % 10;

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: If there are some 20 or 25 digits in the number, then the process becomes difficult

Comment: @LordRishav Typical `int` (32-bit long) nor `long long` (64-bit long) cannot store 25 digit number. The number may be stored as string or other multiple-length format. If the number is stored as string, it will be trivial to get each digits because each characters should represent each digits. If multiple-length integer is used, there may be an interface to convert them to string in the library.

Comment: It becmoes difficult as a direct result of you insisting on not using an array.

Comment: @LordRishav You could create a function. `int f(int n, int d) { return (n / d) % 10; }` and then have `int a = f(num, 1); int b=f(num, 2); int c=f(num, 3); ` etc

Comment: @klutt Your invokation or implimation of the function is wrong. The number should be devided by `pow(10, i)` or `pow(10, i - 1)` instead of `i` (`pow` here is for communication and actual `pow` function shouldn't be used because what we want to do is dealing with integers and the `pow` function in the standard C library is for floating-point numbers)